Getting an error of No module named 'psycopg2' when using Testcontainers-postgres in Python
I have a session.py file that looks like this:
"""Session module to create a session for the PostgreSQL database."""
from os import environ  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, sessionmaker
from testcontainers.postgres import PostgresContainer  # type: ignore

if environ.get("PYTHON_ENV") == "test":
    with PostgresContainer(image="postgres:13") as _postgres:
        DATABASE_URL = _postgres.get_connection_url()
else:
    DATABASE_URL = environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "")

print(f"DATABASE_URL: [{DATABASE_URL}]")
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


# pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    """Base class for the database models.

    This is used instead of declarative_base() because typing tools understand it.
    https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#step-one-orm-declarative-base-is-superseded-by-orm-declarativebase
    """

I am using the following tools:

Poetry for dependency management and packaging.
Pants as a build system.
Github Actions for CI pipeline.
Testcontainers-postgres for running tests in the CI pipeline.
Python Fast-API

The issue is in the test workflow, which I run through the command:
pants test ::

The error is:
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
/home/runner/.cache/pants/named_caches/pex_root/venvs/s/c7e9f9b3/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py:281: in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
/home/runner/.cache/pants/named_caches/pex_root/venvs/s/c7e9f9b3/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py:599: in create_engine
    dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
/home/runner/.cache/pants/named_caches/pex_root/venvs/s/c7e9f9b3/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py:690: in import_dbapi
    import psycopg2
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

I’m not sure why this comes up because psycopg2 is included in my .toml and .lock files. I even ran a new CI workflow in which I explicitly install psycopg2 using pip but I am getting the same error.

I was able to fix this issue by adding import psycopg2 in the code I shared above for session.py.
import psycopg2  # type: ignore # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import

I am getting another error right now that the localhost connection was refused for connecting to the postgres testcontainers. But since that is a different issue, I'll mark this as resolved.
